# Pipeline in Pyspark ML 2.4.0 with OneHotEncoder, to migrate to Pyspark 3.0.0

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, version, one-hot-encoding

I have created a PipelineModel with Pyspark 2.4.0 with several OneHotEncoder (and not OneHotEncoderEstimator).

The steps can be summarized with this kind of snippet :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector, SparseVector, Vectors, VectorUDT, Vector

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler

data = [(1, 2), (0, 1), (4, 5)]

columns = ["cd_tail_unit_urbn","niveau_prix"]

test= spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

for colToEncode in columns : 
    encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol = colToEncode, outputCol = colToEncode + 'classVec')
    stages+=[encoder]
assemblerInputs = [c + "classVec" for c in toEncode]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(test)
test_vect= pipelineModel.transform(test)

pipelineModel.save('xxx/test_ohe')
```

The data platform I'm using is currently testing migrating to Pyspark 3.0.0 and when loading the pipeline, I have the following error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2253.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipelineModel.read loaded a stage but found it was not a Transformer.  Bad stage OneHotEncoder_12f259fd25f8 of type class org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder
```

From what I encontered online, it seems that it's because OneHotEncoder in Pyspark 3.0.0 was deprecated, and OneHotEncoderEstimator was renamed to OneHotEncoder.

How to solve this issue? Retrieving the data I had when I created the Pipeline is not possible. I can load the Pipeline in our Pyspark 2.4.0 version and try to modify the problematic steps, but I'm not sure what metadata or parameters to change.